# Should I define functions that take the same argument or cast to a class that has instance functions in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, oop

I come from a school-centric OOP background, when I have a set of functions that operate on the same set of data my instinct is to create a class with instance functions

ex:

```
class Hand{
  rank
  suit

  getHandName()
  getHandScore()
  isBetterThan(Hand)
  etc()
}
```

In Typescript, especially when dealing with APIs, it seems like a bit of a pain to constantly cast received JSON into an actual class instance to gain access to such functions.  I could just have a bunch of functions that take a Hand interface as an argument, but it seems like boiler-plate to have a bunch of functions taking the exact same parameter...

Is there any sort of "best practice" to do in this situation?  Writing this out now, it seems like maybe I could use closures to have a `function handEval(Hand){}` that avoids having to pass the same parameter, as well as avoiding a ton of un-contained hand-eval functions.

I could also create a HandEvalService class that operates similar to a closure.  It seems weird to have to `new HandEvalService(hand)` just to get the name of a hand though.

Comment: Wrap it in an class. Textbook use-case for encapsulation. You only wrap the object once and then get the benefits back every time you call one of the relevant methods.

Comment: When you say wrap in a class, are you saying take/store the data object from a constructor parameter?  If so I'll lose direct access to the data properties, unless I want to write a bunch of getters for all the properties of the wrapped object.  I guess getters are considered best practice though so maybe that's how I should do it.

Answer (score 0):

What's so different about TypeScript? Would you ask whether or not you should parse JSON into a proper class in Java? Most likely not! If you want to leverage OO there's no other way than parsing the payload into class instances.

> but it seems like boiler-plate to have a bunch of functions taking the exact same parameter...

It may appear to you as "boiler-plate", but a more functional approach is also perfectly valid.

Comment: Yeah I guess my question might be better written as "how do I do OO instance methods in functional programming, is it somehow better/worse than just making a class?"

Comment: OO and functional are mutually exclusive paradigms. OO objects are state + behavior where functional programming is pure functions operating over data structures.

Comment: @Nerdsie Neither are better nor worse. If you want OO you will have to wrap your data in a class and if you just want to cast to an interface then embrace functional programming.